# Border redraw mismatch in React tables

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, html-table, redraw

I'm brand new to React and CSS, and so I decided to make a calculator web app. Everything works as intended except the borders. Sometimes when I check or uncheck operations, the borders between rows won't line up across columns. They can then fix themselves after more clicks. More strangely, I haven't run into this issue when testing it in Firefox. I'm using `border-collapse` in the CSS file. I've included the core of the table code and style below. Thanks for any help!

index.css

```
#output {
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

#result {
  border:4px solid #000;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

#result td {
  border:1px solid #000;
}

#result th {
  border:1px solid #000;
  border-bottom:2px solid #000;
  padding: 10px;
}

#result tr td {
  padding: 4px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  width: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

index.js

```css
function Output(props) {
  const tableData = [];
  const n1 = parseInt(props.num1);
  const n2 = parseInt(props.num2);
  if (props.doAdd)  tableData.push({key: 'addRow', op: 'Addition',       num: add(n1, n2)});
  if (props.doSub)  tableData.push({key: 'subRow', op: 'Subtraction',    num: subtract(n1, n2)});
  if (props.doMul)  tableData.push({key: 'mulRow', op: 'Multiplication', num: multiply(n1, n2)});
  if (props.doDiv)  tableData.push({key: 'divRow', op: 'Division',       num: divide(n1, n2)});

  return (
    <div id='output'>
      <ResultTable data={tableData} />
    </div>
  );
}

function ResultTable(props) {
  let rows = props.data.map(row => {
    return <ResultRow key={row.key} op={row.op} num={row.num} />
  });

  return (
    <table id='result'>
      <thead>{<ResultHead />}</thead>
      <tbody>{rows}</tbody>
    </table>
  );
}

function ResultHead() {
  return (
    <tr>
      <th>Operation</th>
      <th>Result</th>
    </tr>
  );
}

function ResultRow(props) {
  return (
    <tr>
      <td>{props.op}</td>
      <td>{props.num}</td>
    </tr>
  );
}
```

Comment: Can you pack this into a stackblitz or something...

Comment: @EugeneSunic Stackblitz: https://react-aqyy9r.stackblitz.io. Example of issue: https://imgur.com/a/QmxJL77

Comment: @EugeneSunic Hmm, try https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-aqyy9r

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work

Remove   `border-collapse: collapse;` and add `border-spacing: 0;` instead.

```
#result {
      border:4px solid #000;
      border-spacing: 0;
    }
```

Working example on stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-aqyy9r

Comment: I just tried this, and it's still having the same issue with and without min-height

Comment: Removing border-collapse worked! It made the border much thicker though, but I think I can fix that by playing with the border widths. Thanks so much!!

Comment: Yes, sorry, my comment was from before your edit. Thanks again!

Answer (score -2):

What happens is that you are not giving a set Height to each .

At some point in the same row, one column has height 38.5px and other 40px. That's why you see the mismatch between the borders.

You can easily fix this by adding min-height

```
   #result tr td {
     min-height: 40px;
   }
```

Comment: Hmm, this still didn't fix the problem. I tried various increasing numbers all the way to 300px, and it still continued to end up mis-matched.